Unable to upload app on google play console. Google Play Core (com.google.android.play:core) has added this note for SDK version 1.10.3:
While uploading the previous Android application, the Google Play Store warned me to update the core library before 31st August 2024, However, I requested a Google Play console for extension and the console confirmed that I would not be able to upload apps with the older core library after 24th October 2024.
Today when I tried to upload a new version of my application, Google Play Store is not allowing me to upload the app and gave the following error
.
It is important to publish the app today and we cannot go into UAT/QA cycle again after updating core library right now. What should we do in this case? As we already had taken extension for this from google play developer console.
Edit : As per below screenshot, we won't be able to upload apps with deprecated core library after 24th October 2024.


I have added screenshot for extension till 24th October as well in the post.

Are you sure the extension was for this issue?
Your only options are:

Upgrade the version of Play Core to the one marked in the message then reupload the AAB.
Contact developer support and ask for a temporary exemption. It will take a few days and may or may not be granted.


Yes. I have added screenshot for extension till 24th October as well in the post.
